# Ubuntu cannot see node, Git Bash can, AND other stuff

Tags: ubuntu, git-bash

I have both Ubuntu and Git Bash in my PC.

- When I type LS command on Ubuntu, nothing shows up.
- When I type LS on Git Bash, it lists the directory.

And:

- When I look for the version for NODE and NPM, it works for Git Bash
- but Ubuntu doesn't see NODE or NPM and ask if I want to download it.

However, when following along with my Bootcamp's lesson, some commands don't work for both Git Bash and Ubuntu.
Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Are you indeed using WSL2 on Windows 10?

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu should be available through WSL2, which means the [folder used inside a WSL2 Ubuntu session](https://askubuntu.com/a/759885/5470) might not be the same as the one used in a git bash session.

And the `$PATH` in both session might differ.

- A Git bash session would inherit from the Windows `%PATH%` environment variable, which might include `node.exe`/`npm.exe` Windows Node distribution already installed there.
- a WSL2 Ubuntu session would use Linux Node distribution, that [need to be installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl#install-nvm-nodejs-and-npm) first.